# How to keep client request alive for delayed response from server in jsf

Tags: javascript, jquery, http, jsf, primefaces

I have a p:commandButton in my JSF page. When user clicks there is a huge amount of data being retrieved from the database and written in excel file and returned to user as a response. This can take up to hours. But after almost one hour using IE it shows "cannot load the page" error message even the process remains running at server side. I know it happens due to client's configuration for expected response time from server. it differs from browser to browser.

Even tough, i am continuously sending ajax updates from server to client during the calculation to show the percentage of the processed data to user and it works but still my client gets dead. Moreover, there is a p:progressBar on my JSF page, which is also showing the percentage in it's every update intervals.

How can I keep my client alive through code? So that after sending a request, it can wait for a long time for the response.

We have different users using different browsers. I need a solution which works for all major browsers. This is my code.

```
<p:dialog id="alert-exp-info-dialog"
          widgetVar="alertExpInfoDialog">

    <p:ajax event="close"
            listener="#{bean.onExportDialogClose}"
            process="@this"
            update=":alert-exp-info-form"
            immediate="true" />

    <h:form id="alert-exp-info-form">

        <h:outputFormat id="alert-exp-detail"
                        value="So info for user">
            <f:param value="#{bean.exportedAlertsCount}" />
            <f:param value="#{bean.totalExportableAlerts}" />
        </h:outputFormat>

        <p:progressBar id="alert-exp-progress" 
                        widgetVar="alertExpProgress"  
                        value="#{bean.exportProgress}" 
                        labelTemplate="{value}%"
                        interval="3000"
                        ajax="true">
                <p:ajax event="complete" 
                        listener="# {bean.onExportComplete}"/>
                <f:event type="preValidate" 
                        update="alert-exp-abort-btn" 
                        listener="#{bean.updateComponents}" />
        </p:progressBar>

        <h:panelGroup id="alert-exp-button-panel">
        <p:commandButton id="alert-exp-proceed-btn"
                        value="Process"
                        action="#{bean.doCalculation}"
                        onclick="alertExpProgress.start();"
                        ajax="false">
            <p:ajax update="alert-exp-button-panel" />
        </p:commandButton>
        </h:panelGroup>

    </h:form>

</p:dialog>

public void doCalculation()
{
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    //Too long calculation...
    for ( loop )
    {
    ...
    ...
    }
    //Finally writing excel file on responce
    context.setResponseContentType( "application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" );
    context.setResponseHeader( "Expires", "0" );
    context.setResponseHeader( "Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-  check=0, pre-check=0" );
    context.setResponseHeader( "Pragma", "public" );
    context.setResponseHeader( "Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + ( fileName.endsWith( ".xlsx" ) ? fileName : fileName + ".xlsx" ) );
    context.addResponseCookie( Constants.DOWNLOAD_COOKIE, "true", new HashMap<String, Object>() );

    OutputStream out = context.getResponseOutputStream();
    generatedExcel.write( out );
    out.close();
    context.responseFlushBuffer();
    context.responseComplete();
}  

public void updateComponents()
{
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update( "alert-exp-info-form:alert-    exp-detail" );
}

public void onExportComplete()
{
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.execute("alertExpInfoDialog.hide();");
}
```

Comment: Trying to keep request alive that long doesn't really make sense. Why can't you make additional request to get the data after process completes?

Comment: @Undertaker What is client expected to do with response? What do you mean by _"Continuously updating client with percentage"_ ? Is that description not opposite from _"So that after sending a request, it can wait for a long time for the response."_? Have you tried using `WebSocket`?

Comment: Edited question. I am writing excel file at response which appears as a popup in UI and user can save or open it from the browser. May be should i use onExportComplete() to write the file in response?

Comment: No, don't use the oncomplete of the ajax call either. Use ajax to start generating the file in a fire-and-forget way. Then use websockets to update the client with the percentage complete and when that receives a 100% complete, you can do the actual download.

Comment: Plus 1 for suggestion to do this on ajax event. Now the only problem is that how to make the file downloadable via RequestContext? before i was writing the file in action method on button click using FacesContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by triggering the long processing via ajax and finally download the generated excel file via a separate button click.